# Chrome extension not working in one computer

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have developed a chrome extension that i have tested successfully in two different computers (Linux and Windows systems) with Chrome version 76.0. The first line of this extension is a console.log("test") which is obviously showing in the developer console every time i start chrome. The problem I face now is that when testing the extension in a MAC computer (which should not make a difference?) with Chrome 76.0, it is installed successfully but it never starts. Not a single log is shown (yes, i checked that logs are being shown) and it is not working at all. No error are shown in the console and no errors in the extension settings tab. I have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: Make sure there's no **filter** applied in devtools console toolbar. P.S. Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) you're unlikely to get help here.

Comment: Yes, it is not about the filter, the extension is not doing anything at all. There are visuals hints that i would see if it were working. And yes, I know that with this description I won't get much help but to be honest, It makes so little sense that I don't know what else I can share.

Comment: If it's a content script it may be blocked in `runtime_blocked_hosts` which you can see in `chrome://policy`